# Magento cant select second attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes

I have products that have multiple attributes the user can choose from. The problem is the second attribute is visible on the product page but the user can't select it, even if they have chosen a value for the first attribute. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if "use in navigation layer" is set to yes, that can be found under catalog->attributes->manage attributes.